# How to Update Entity by Replacing in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class `Order` which has a `List<Item>` and a `Customer`. I need to update `Order` and its child class. First I only attach the `Order` object 
but in this way EF cannot Understand changes in `Items` and `Customers`.

Then I tried changing the state of the child classes to `EntityState.Modified` but that didn't work either.Is there a way in EF to replac parent and child classes with existing record in db?

And if there isn't, how can I solve this problem?

```
var temp = db.Orders.Find(order.Id);
temp = order;
temp.Items = order.Items;
temp.Customer = order.Customer; 
db.SaveChanges();
```

i try this too after changing Order in user actions:

```
db.Orders.Attach(order) ;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Are you trying to say you are changing model and the you are expecting it's impact on database? But is has no impact on db. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes... fetch an "Order" record from db to object and modify it's child classes but EF don't save this change in DB

Comment: You doing `Database.SaveChanges()` ? (replace Database with your Object)

Comment: yes ... i update my question with my code.

Comment: Does it return an error? wrap it in a `try{}catch(Exception ex){}`, your question is confusing because what you're trying to do works fine for me, use constructors

Comment: no error no exception

Comment: You are not adding your object probably.                                                 Db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.SaveChanges();

Comment: not fully understanding what `temp = order;` is doing but i assume you haven't either created the object or added it? I think @bluetoothfx 's comment should work :) good luck

Comment: i need to update my existing record. adding new record is not my goal

Comment: Use EntityState.Modified

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I haven't tried this for Entities with Child classes but you could try setting the value.

```
context.Entry(temp).CurrentValues.SetValues(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes that order is an instance of the Entity Orders. Note this will completely overwrite every property of the temp record with that of order.

This blog has more information (Also applies to EF Core): https://web.archive.org/web/20191225092110/http://kerryritter.com/updating-or-replacing-entities-in-entity-framework-6/

Comment: This code worked for me: `context.Update(temp).CurrentValues.SetValues(order);`. Although it doesn't work for child entities.

Comment: @Alex Zhukovskiy and Dale C - Thanks for your post, that worked fine!
Dale - Could you update the link please, it gets a 404 back ...

Comment: This is GOOD! Update failed me.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to replace entity with related/child/nested references and collections you can use Tracked Graph since **EF Core 2.2**. All entities IDs should be database generated.

Add method to your context

```cs
public void Replace<TEntity>(TEntity oldEntity, TEntity newEntity) where TEntity : class
{
    ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(oldEntity, e => e.Entry.State = EntityState.Deleted);
    ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(newEntity, e => e.Entry.State = e.Entry.IsKeySet ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added);
}
```

Usage

```cs
var oldOrder = db.Orders
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(o => o.Items)
        .Include(o => o.Customer)
        .Find(newOrder.Id);

db.Replace(oldOrder, newOrder);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Note that old entity should be detatched using **AsNoTracking** or

```cs
db.Entry(oldOrder).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Answer (score 2):

On EF6, there's no built in *reliable* way to attach a full graph (including related items) on a context (other than `Add()`, but that doesn't update, just adds). In fact, it's *supposed* to work (and attach full object graphs), but in practice, it doesn't work and it's very inconsistent, so it's always better to attach every related item yourself.

There are third-party tools like [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) that may help with this task (check its extension method, `DbContext.UpdateGraph()`), but there is no *reliable* built-in way.

I'm not sure if EF Core has implemented it already, but it was under discussion (there was [this issue going on at GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2726) *-it's for `Add` but you'll see `Update` mentioned throughout the discussion-*). It's however closed and I'm not following closely though to know if there are related issues opened)

Answer (score -1):

No need to attach order for update. Use like below:

```
Db.Entry(temp).State = EntityState.Modified;
Db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Db.Entry(temp).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: i use it but get this Exception "Attaching an entity of type 'DataAccess.Order' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value"

Comment: That's because you executed a Find() that loaded the record from the database into the entity cache. Then you assigned a new object and attached it to the context, creating a new entry with the same key (order.ID). When you hit SaveChanges(), EF rightfully complained about the two entries with the same key.